# Transaction fail (Tx is Successful in Remix)

Tags: ethereumjs, web3.py

I get a transaction failed when trying to execute the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
  pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
  contract state {    
      uint256 contract_version = 1;
      function set_version(uint256 cv_n) public {
                contract_version = cv_n;
      }
      function get_version() public view returns (uint256) {
                return contract_version;
      }
  }
  contract complicated {
     state st;
     constructor() public {
            address st_address = new state();
            st = state(st_address);
     }
     function set_version(uint256 cv_n) public {
            st.set_version(cv_n);
     }
     function get_version() public view returns (uint256) {
            return st.get_version();
     }
  }
```

And to execute the contract using solidity I use the following code derived from the example:

```
compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code) # Compiled source code
contract_interface = compiled_sol['<stdin>:complicated']


w3 = Web3(Web3.TestRPCProvider())

w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]


Greeter = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])

tx_hash = Greeter.constructor().transact()

tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

greeter = w3.eth.contract(
    address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
    abi=contract_interface['abi']
)

tx_hash = greeter.functions.set_version(10).transact()

w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

print('Updated contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.get_version().call()
))
```

Using Web3py I get the following error message:

> ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'Server error', 'data':
>   {'type': 'TransactionFailed', 'args': [], 'message': ''}}

When I import the contact to remix the contract works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code)

Change the code above to the following:

```
compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code, evm_version='homestead')
```

Solidity versions post 0.4.22 have introduced two new opcodes, which aren't implemented in pyethereum which was causing the TransactionFailed error. To know more read [this article](https://medium.com/@chris_77367/explaining-unexpected-reverts-starting-with-solidity-0-4-22-3ada6e82308c).